# how to link user of one model class to another user of a foreign class in django views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I've created an app where by a user can create a job and the other user can apply to that specific job, so far creating a job is not a problem but for the other user to apply for that specific job  it is quite hard for a beginner like me. I've created tried this way down here but failed and got errors, though for me i think the problem is with my poor views

models.py

```
class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='applied_jobs',
     null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='applications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    career_briefing = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

form.py

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        field = ['career_briefing',]
```

views.py

```
class JobDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Job
    template_name = 'jobs/job_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JobDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class ApplicationCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    template_name = 'jobs/application_form.html'
    message = _("succesfuly created")


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ApplicationForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form) 
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.job = self.kwargs["job_id"]
        apply = form.save(commit=False):
        apply.user = self.request.user
        apply.job = self.object
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, self.message)
        return reverse(
           "jobs:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.kwargs["job_id"]})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^details/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', JobDetailView.as_view(), 
name='detail'),
    url(r'^details/apply/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ApplicationCreateView.as_view(), name='apply'),

    ....

]
```

templates.py

```
    ....
<div>
      <a class="btn btn-dark" href="{% url 'jobs:apply' job.id %}">{% trans 'apply' %}</a>    
    </div>
    ....
```

i expect that once the user clicks apply button, should be added to the applied list the redirected back to the details page,BUT i get an error which says that

```
 TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

here is the full trace back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 134, in render_to_response
    template=self.get_template_names(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 126, in get_template_names
    names = super().get_template_names()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 147, in get_template_names
    "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

Comment: can you please post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @ruddra i have already Updated my question you can check the trace back

Comment: um, can you plz share your `JobDetailView`?

Comment: i've just updated  the question  youcan check please @ruddra

Comment: You need to specify a model for the create view `model=Application`

Comment: let me try that